# Survival analysis using as exposure a case-control study variable

Tags: survival, weights, case-control-study

I have doubts about how to correctly analyze the following study, since it is neither a nested case control nor a case-cohort study, but it is a previous matched case-control study in which the "Case / Control" variable will now be an exposure variable with exposure time.

For a population (a whole country) I have **ALL** the stomach cancer survivors. However instead of having all people free of the disease (and have the full cohort) I have 5 controls for each case (paired by sex and birth year). Being a cancer survivor in the study will be the exposure and we will look at whether or not these survivors are at higher risk of another outcome (another disease). I have to take into account the exposure time (the time during which they have been at risk being cancer survivors) so I need to do a survival analysis model (a Cox PH or an extension).

Do you think I could do a regular Cox model, since the over representation is in an explanatory variable and not in the response? Or that I should do a weighting of 1 in the cases, and in the controls the inverse of the probability of having been selected? Or some other kind of approach, such a frailty term for each matched group?